# Python numeric values for letters in string

Tags: python

I am having trouble solving the following question,

> Q: Given a string find out the total sum of all the numbers.
>   Values are as A-1, B-10, C-100, D-1000, E-10000.
>
> Ex. DDBC. Answer is 1000+1000+10+100 = 2110.

Comment: What's the trouble you're having? You seem to get the idea just fine.. have you tried to code this and failed?

Comment: You will find you get far more helpful attention when you give some indication of what you have done to try and solve the problem yourself before asking here. I'm not trying to be abrasive, that's just how it goes :) And in the end, it's better for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just deduce the power of 10 by the position of the letter:

```
s = "DDBC"

result = sum(10**(ord(c)-ord('A')) for c in s)
```

result: 2110

You can filter out lowercase letters & other chars easily, but that complexifies a little bit:

```
result = sum(10**(ord(c.upper())-ord('A')) for c in s if c.isalpha())
```

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to go about this.

Here's one idea:

Make a lookup that maps letters to the their values. Something like:

```
import string
lookup =  {s: 10**i for i,s in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}
```

Lookup will be a dictionary like:

> {
>   'A': 1,
>       'B': 10,
>      'C': 100,
>    'D': 1000,
>    'E': 10000,
>    'F': 100000,
>    ...
>   }

With that you can use a comprehension and take the sum:

```
>> s = "DDBC"
>> sum(lookup[l] for l in s)
2110
```

This, of course, assumes your string is all uppercase, like the example you posted.

Comment: `dict((s,10**i) for i,s in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase))` is very old python for `{s:10**i for i,s in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}`

Comment: `lookup[l]` => `lookup.get(l.upper(),0)` so if lowercase it works, and if any other character, you get 0

Comment: Good notes — thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching the string, and every instance of that letter occurring causes you to add to total.

For instance:

```
total = 0
input_string = input()
for i in len(input_string):
    if input_string[i] == "A":
        total += 1
```

and then you can repeat that for the other instances of the other characters.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Sorry about last comment, always mix up my string and list methods.